# Cordova alarm clock

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have built a Cordova alarm clock app that has a timer.  Everything works good except that I now want to inform the user when the clock is up with a visual and audio alarm.

I have used the following plugin for local notifications: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

This seems to work good except that it doesn't seem to work when the phone screen is off.

Any ideas of a better way of doing this.  I probably want something like AlarmManager in Android but so far I haven't found a Cordova plugin for it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked this plugin?

https://github.com/uniclau/AlarmPlugin

To invoke the plugin:

```
navigator.plugins.alarm.set(alarmDate, 
   function(){
       // SUCCESS
   }, 
   function(){
       // ERROR
   }
);
```

`alarmDate` is the date that the application will wake up. This will happen even if the device has been **rebooted**.

Comment: is there a solution for iOS?

Comment: @HarryMoreno buy an android! 

Comment: Thanks @AAhad however I could not make the plugin work as I was not aware what the format of the date. An example of alarmDate would really help.

Answer (score 4):

@AAhad your answer inspired mine.
https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer is a plugin that works for both iOS and Android devices.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i'm very new to mobile development, and cannot figure out a couple of things. Is it possible to schedule a task with this this plugin? Does the alarm work if the application is off? Does this plugin work with _Ionic_ framework? Thanks!

Comment: Plugin should be able to work with ionic. You may have to perform extra steps to make it work with ionic though. I think the module sets an alarm within the app (not the built-in alarm for the phone) but you should test it out or ask the author.