# How do I access the iPhone system clock with IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, clock, alarm

I'm creating an alarm clock application and I would like to know how to access the native iOS system clock with IONIC.

Comment: You need a cordova plugin for that. I'm not sure if there is one though. I'm going to search for one now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova alarm clock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962162/cordova-alarm-clock)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access specific system features like this, you'll need to install a cordova plugin (ionic is built on top of cordova).

See this similar question for example: [Cordova alarm clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962162/cordova-alarm-clock)